# How to mock a class attribute in Python Mockito

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mockito

I'm writing test cases using Mockito. My code looks like this

```
def function_to_test():
    dog = lib1.get_dog()
    return dog.weight
```

My test code looks like this

```
def test_method1():
    dog_mock = mock()
    when(lib1).get_dog().thenReturn(dog_mock)
    when(dog).weight.thenReturn(10)  # <-- I'm not sure how do I write this?
```

As `dog.weight` is not a method. How do I mock it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familiar with Mockito framework for Python, but I think you should just set the property on the mock object. Something like that:

```
dog_mock = mock()
dog_mock.weight = 100
when(lib1).get_dog().thenReturn(dog_mock)
```

Comment: To configure attributes it should also be possible to just do `mock({'weight': 100})`.